# Issue with using tf.contrib.layers.group_norm with variable batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, normalization

I am trying to use group norm as part of my CNN. But I get the following error which I believe is tied to the fact that the first dimension of the placeholder for my input images, being the batch size, is set to None. The group norm implementation involves a reshape operation that doesn't play well with this. Could you kindly suggest a workaround for this?

TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: [None, 16, 64, 64, 12, 2]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue on Tensorflow and you can read up more about it here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24409

In short, this error is due to [normalization.py#L303](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.12/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/normalization.py#L303) and can be fixed with the addition of the following two lines after Line 252 in normalization.py:

```
original_shape = [-1 if s.value is None else s for s in original_shape]
if len([s for s in original_shape if s == -1]) > 1:
    raise ValueError('Only one axis dimension can be undefined in the input tensor')
```

and the following line after Line 302:

```
inputs_shape = [-1 if s is None else s for s in inputs_shape]
```

Source: [This](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24409) issue on the tensorflow github page.